# i am trying to share video to twitter from my iOS app but it keep asking login

Tags: ios, twitter

```
  - (void) share:(NSString*)filename {

    BOOL status = [[TwitterVideoUpload instance] setVideo:filename];
    if (status == FALSE) {
        [self addText:@"Failed reading video file"];
        return;
    }

     status = [[TwitterVideoUpload instance] upload:^(NSString* errorString)
      {
           NSString* printStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Share video %@: %@", filename,(errorString == nil) ? @"Success" : errorString];
              [self addText:printStr];
      }];


     if (status == FALSE) {
        [self addText:@"No Twitter account. Please add twitter account to Settings app."];
     }
}
```

> this is my code, even after login into twitter in my simulator and browser it keep saying "Not logged in". Any solution?

[image]

Comment: how did you log into Twitter in the simulator?  Also, did you include the `Social.framework` from the iOS SDK?  Are you using `SLRequest` anywhere?

Comment: cmnd+shft+H to come out all apps and i logged in simulator safari twitter

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rugJR.png

Answer (score 0):

According to the ReadMe document for [the TwitterVideoUpload repo](https://github.com/mtrung/TwitterVideoUpload):

> Twitter username + password must be provided to iOS Settings app

Logging in via Mobile Safari isn't going to do it.

You need to use iOS ***Settings*** to authenticate to Twitter.